# Joomla Admin Side URL Changed from `&` to `&amp;` in URL String

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

i had change server of my joomla website
but i got now some issue in administrator panel the URL of Page has been changed from `&` to `&amp;`

When i tried to edit any Article its give lock option near the name mins checkin, i dont understand whats that and url will goes like this

```
http://60pluslife.org/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;layout=edit&amp;id=2
```

actually url is that

```
http://60pluslife.org/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=2
```

Give me Suggestions Please

Comment: I think it changed from `&` to `&amp;`

Comment: :) ya thts rite its my fault :)

Comment: I think you need to communicate with your host

Comment: I think so... Let me ask them

Comment: Is it possible you have different character encoding on your database?

Comment: IT was some Host Provider Error it solved